# Is there a way to get hold of child records after a cascaded delete of parent record in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

How can one get hold of the deleted child record when the parent record is deleted in postgresql? I have two tables that are related. The foreign table have a foreign key that has the constraint of `on delete cascade`. I would like to get hold of the child record after deleting the parent record.
The tables are as follows:

```
create table table1( 
 id int not null primary key
);
create table table2( 
 id int not null primary key, 
 table1id int not null, 
 foreign key(table1id) references table1(id) on delete cascade
);
```

Assume the tables have records.

```
 table1
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+

 table2
| id | table1id |
+----+----------+
| 1  |  1       |
+----+----------+
```

So I want to delete the records after retrieving the child records using one statement.
I tried `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = 1) RETURNING *` but it only returns the table1 records and not at least table2 record. table2 deleted record is what I want to use after the deletion. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you realize that there could be **other** records in table2 with table1id=1 ? (-->> `NOT EXISTS()` )

Comment: It is a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: Then you don't need two tables.

Comment: Table1 is also related to 2 other tables. If I collapse the tables into one, it will fail 3NF and thus hampering the operations of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you will have to delete the table2's registries first, returning the values, then delete the table1's registries based in your returned values..

don't forget to set all this process in a transaction.

(but, i can't imagine your use case for this, sorry)

Comment: The **id** in the child record is later used for subsequent operation of deleting a resource in a cloud service. I would like to know how I can achieve it. If I change the entity relationship it becomes messy.

Comment: for this use case I would suggest to add trigger on delete event to insert the ids in other table to be used as a "queue list" to hold the resource's ids to delete in the cloud..

then when you remove from the cloud you remove from this "queue list" table.

Comment: I have resorted to retrieving the child record first before deleting the entire records.